# Failed to transform file 'linkedin-sdk-release.aar' to match attributes

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate LinkedIn into my Android app and am getting a response

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Failed to transform file
>   'linkedin-sdk-release.aar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform
>   ExtractAarTransform

If someone can help, please.

My buld.gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "e.musalastborn.truckers1"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        cxxxxxxc
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
}

//dependencies added to the app.
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile project(path: ':linkedin-sdk', configuration: 'default')
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.6.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-nop:1.7.25'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'

}
```

Comment: Please share `build.gradle` file of your app

Comment: @VicJodan, I just shared my gradle. Kindly assist.

Comment: @Sufferer Did you solve this...

Comment: @ Tash Pemhiwa, No i din't. It made me put the project on hold!

Answer (score 1):

this problem probably happened after you make some changes with `linkedin-sdk-release.aar`.

just like me, I open that aar and delete some directories before I include in my project.

while I confuse with this error, I run **gradlew** with option `--stacktrace`:

`./gradlew :app:assembleDebug --stacktrace`

the output is (omitted detail strack trace):

```

> Task :app:checkDebugClasspath FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Failed to transform file 'mmkv-1.0.13.aar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-exploded-aar} using transform ExtractAarTransform
  >   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED
  >   ```

saw the `MALFORMED` keyword I notice my fault, then I extract the origin aar and do the job like before(delete some directories), I re-compress the changed by zip application(ubuntu's default compress tool).

of course the error gone.